# Cat sisters that don't get along

Tags: cats

I have two cats, two sisters, that always lived together. When they were kittens, we lived in a big house with a garden in which they could play or hunt. But I moved to a smaller appartment with both of them a few years ago. They are now eleven years old.

At the beggining everything was okay, but now they fight each other often. One of them seem to be very stressed out. I tried using attractive scents that the vet gave me, but it doesn't seem to work very well. I can't separate them either : I live in a rather small appartment and it would be plain cruel to limit one of them to a small room.

What can I do to make them relax and accept each other ?

Comment: Are they both spayed?

Comment: Yep, they are both spayed.

Comment: A small space can seem a lot bigger for a cat if you add vertical space - cat trees, shelves, walkways on the walls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a small apartment, vertical space is the key!  Your two 11 year old kitties simply do not have enough room in your apartment. Try creating as much vertical space as you can.

You do this by adding tall cat trees at least 6 to 7 feet tall, with several different levels. Your cats will establish a natural dominance on these levels. Add several window perches, where the cats can look out the window and sleep in the sunbeams.  Be sure to put these on several different windows so both cats can use them at the same time.  You can find window perches at any pet store.

I would also suggest putting up shelves covered in a material they can get their claws into. Make the shelves like stair-steps, starting mid-way on the wall and going up close to the ceiling.  This is just another way they can get more vertical space in a small apartment. You can dress up the shelves, hanging pictures above or below the shelves - just not on the shelves.

The idea is to make your apartment fun for them. You have to think like a cat, even if it means changing your apartment a little. In the end, you will have happy cats. Happy cats, happy home.

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion I've heard for this situation is trying to reintroduce your cats.  You separate your cats, and slowly work them back up to being together, as you would if the cats were complete strangers.  An article detailing the technique: http://www.catbehaviorassociates.com/pams-think-like-a-cat-reintroduction-method/

Another thing you might try is rotating cats, where you separate them, but regularly change which cat is in the smaller space, so they can both enjoy the larger area some of the time.

This sounds like a territory problem.  It may have been your cats only formally got along because they had their established territories in the house, and in this new place, their established territories are gone.  It may be that your new apartment is simply too small to happily accommodate both cats.

Comment: I'll try, thank you ! I hope the appartment isn't to small, because I can't do anything about it at the moment.